# Mouse Cursor Dissapears in VirtualBox (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, mouse

I am currently trying to install os x mountain lion as a guest os on my windows 7 pc so that i can use Xcode.

I am using this guide:

http://lifehacker.com/5938332/how-to-run-mac-os-x-on-any-windows-pc-using-virtualbox

I have just completed step 2.1 BUT when i try to click inside the VirtualBox window my cursor dissapears AND stops moving.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is the behaviour when VirtualBox has captured the mouse device for your virtualized operating system.  As it once told you.

[image: VirtualBox mouse capture warning]

You have three choices:

1. Live with this.  Avoid clicking within the VirtualBox window, and press the "host" key to uncapture whenever necessary.
2. Install the *experimental* MacOS 10 guest additions.
3. Have a non-PS/2 mouse device in the virtual machine.

### Further reading

- Oracle corporation (2014).  ["Capturing and releasing keyboard and mouse"](http://virtualbox.org./manual/ch01.html#keyb_mouse_normal).  Oracle VM VirtualBox manual.

Comment: 1. I cannot live with this because the mouse does not work inside the virtualbox window at all.
2. Can you please link a relevant experimental guest addition?
3. the mouse i am using currently is usb 2.0 and is listed as a USB device under devices in the virtualbox window.

Thanks